# ROW_NUMBER error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT [Column1] FROM VIEW1 WHERE ROW_NUMBER = 5;
```

gives an error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Invalid column name 'ROW_NUMBER'.

Any suggestions as to why? ROW_NUMBER is colored in a shade of pink automatically, which means from my knowledge "keyword" - so why does Sql Server think it should be a column and says the column doesn't exist?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you handle the query is wrong because

***ROW_NUMBER Returns the sequential number of
 a row within a partition of a result set,
 starting at 1 for the first row in each    partition.***

You  can try

```
Select 
from 
(
        Select row_number() over (partition by x order by x)SrNo,* from x
)A
where A.SrNo=1
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use `ROW_NUMBER` in this context. An example of using `ROW_NUMBER` in a WHERE clause can be seen here:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
WITH OrderedOrders AS
(
    SELECT SalesOrderID, OrderDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderDate) AS RowNumber
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
) 
SELECT SalesOrderID, OrderDate, RowNumber  
FROM OrderedOrders 
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 50 AND 60;
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can't use ROW_NUMBER() like that

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT [Column1], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER By [Column1] ASC) As Row
    FROM VIEW1
) x
WHERE Row = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define `ROW_NUMBER` first. Try this...

```
SELECT [column1] FROM (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY key ASC) AS rownumber,
    [column1]
  FROM <tablename>
) AS xyz
WHERE rownumber = 5
```

For Example:

```
SELECT EmpName FROM (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY empId ASC) AS rownumber,
    EmpName
  FROM EmpMaster
) AS EmpTable
WHERE rownumber = 5
```

You can use *View* instead of *Table*